SSH failing with "ssh_rsa_verify: cannot handle type rsa-sha2-256"
I have an old Server (Centos 4 - yes it will be upgraded but not yet!) and a new Backup machine (Rocky 9.5). I previously had rsync from the server to a previous incarnation of the backup machine (Centos 8) working, but the backup server OS died (when I tried to update pacakges...). I want to use rsync -e ssh ... to mirror files from the Server to the Backup.
The issue I have is in getting the two servers to talk over SSH. I have overcome most hurdles by adding into the Backup's SSHD config:
#Legacy changes
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa

That's overcome the initial hurdle of getting old (considered insecure, but this is on my own private network) protocols.
But I can't figure out why the key's don't work.

On Backup I generated a new key that should be SHA1:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -t ssh-rsa -f ssh_host_rsa_key


I did also try with just -t rsa and just -t ssh-rsa. As per man ssh-keygen:

This flag may also be used to specify the desired signature type when signing certificates using an RSA CA key. The available RSA signature variants are ssh-rsa  ...

I was trying to use that to create a SHA1 rather than SHA256 signature.

But the Server fails to connect:
ssh_rsa_verify: cannot handle type rsa-sha2-256
key_verify failed for server_host_key



How do I generate a key that the Server will be acceptable with?
For info, the SSH version on Backup is OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.2.2 and on ServerOpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a.
Additional info, the response on the Server when attempting the connection (actual IP addresses changed to x.x.x.):
    [root@server ssh]# ssh -vvv x.x.x.5 root@backup
OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.5 [x.x.x.5] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.9p1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 161/320
debug2: bits set: 512/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 2
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.5' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
ssh_rsa_verify: cannot handle type rsa-sha2-256
key_verify failed for server_host_key


honest question, because of both the security implications of using a two decades old SSH implementation and because of the potential effort: is it a realistic option to just boot the server off a life medium with a modern OS on it, mount the right file systems and rsync through that?

(I'll go ahead and assume you'd be replacing the hardware anyways – maybe the option of taking the storage medium and showing it into a docking station is available, too?)

The server is still running I don't need to boot off a live CD - First set up in 2006 as a home server so it's been old hardware given a long life. Plus given the age of the hardware a more modern OS may baulk at booting! I do take regular backups of files on USB hard disks (to protect against HDD failure). What's annoying is that I had my scripts working with Centos 8, but simply can't replicate with Rocky 9.5. The scripts are to do nightly backups to another machine.

In addition, when I do build a new server, the best way to copy the current data over will also be rsync (the old disks are PATA, the new machine will almost certainly be SATA). I would also prefer not to take it apart (leave well alone what is working until it's replacement is built). Granted there will probably be other options such as using SAMBA shares but from using rsync that did seem a good way of mirroring files from one machine to another.

that's not what I'm asking – I asked whether it'd be feasible to boot it off a live medium, not whether you need to; this thing is ridiculously outdated, software-wise. Booting off a live medium and then rsyncing from there would be 10 minutes of work (in addition to the actual copy time, which wouldn't change). Understand why I, putting on a "make Pete's life as easy as possible" hat, would go that route rather than trying to downgrade the oldest host key algorithm your rocky linux supports?

No, because the scripts run nightly to backup all files automatically without my interaction. If I have to remember to boot from a live CD and manually run all the rsyncs then that's worse than going and getting USB hard disks and copying using a Windows machine (which I do roughly monthly to have a copy that is not permantently live on the network).

ah, that's additional information you didn't give in the question! I was under the impression this was a one time thing where you put that old server to rest soon after. That changes things! In that case, my professional opinion would still be that you should do that one-time backup, and then update software as soon as possible, but my empathic opinion would be that a statically built modern SSH client to execute on the CentOS 4 machine would probably be what I would do as stopgap measure. Reason:

OpenSSH disabled RSA key acceptance if SHA1 is used in release 8.8 by default; you'd need to build a version of sshd that re-enables that (security-wise, dangerous) option. So, it's "either downgrade one end, or upgrade the other, yourself" for you; and one option gives you a secure link.

On 'server' (which is really SSH client) do a connection attempt with at least ssh -vv (maybe -vvv) and look at the resulting log. If old-client offers only ssh-rsa in its KEXINIT  then it should NOT receive rsa-sha2-256 'key' (really signature methd) from new-server. You might try (only temporarily) HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa (no plus-sign) and see if that makes a difference, though it shouldn't. @MarcusMüller: you don't need to rebuild; the disabling of ssh-rsa is entirely in configuration which OP has already handled.

@dave_thompson_085 these might be redhat patches, but the on my rocky container's sshd, you simply can't enable these via config, I tested that before commenting.

I don't recommend this at all but another option is set the default crypto policies to LEGACY on the Rocky Linux 9.5 machine so that it will accept keys (and certs) with ancient protocols. This isn't best practice but it can be done if you insist on continuing to use a Centos 4 machine.

@dave_thompson_085 removing the + sign made no difference. I think it also accepts ssh-dss. I'll paste the whole debug info (done as an update to the question as I can't see how to paste anywhere else) in case there is anything that I'm not aware of.

@Nasir Riley - Thanks having searched about LEGACY, the RHEL docs helped there and I'm one step closer. Now I just need to figure out why my password is not being accepted:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.

For authentication failures, you might want to check what the server-side log says (/var/log/secure on RHEL and relatives, /var/log/auth.log on Debian and relatives). Also, some very old SSH server implementations get confused by the multitude of options offered by a modern SSH client; in most such cases, the reason is the buffer allocated for protocol options to negotiate is too small. For those, you might have to configure the client to offer only what the old server supports and nothing more.

A little bit closer: Added to /etc/ssh/sshd_config: PermitRootLogin yes
Now the root user password is accepted, but the session is immediately closed without opening a remote shell on Backup.
On Backup the status for sshd states:
Dec 09 22:25:24 Backup sshd[59338]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Dec 09 22:25:24 Backup sshd[59338]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
The only obvious output from the ssh session on Server is bash: root@backup: command not found

If you are using a key and the SSH server is configured properly, then the server won't ask for a password. Do not post information such as what you just added in the comments. Add them to the question so that people can see them immediately instead of them getting lost.

Thanks everyone - Final issue was that the public key from the Server was too short - I generated a new 2048 bit key, added it to Backup and now rsync will connect passwordless. Thanks for everyone's tips (and in a few months I will build a new server and re-enable all the more secure options).
